# Isolating text from the middle of a varchar field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `varchar column` in one of my tables, and I need to be able to isolate some text from the middle of it, so that I can use this to lookup information from another table.

An example of the text this column might contain is like this:

```
0A10-Deeside PKG AHU-G37-Pa-A is out of range (Current value of 12.000000 is greater than the maximum value of 5.000000)
```

In this example, `0A10-Deeside` is data we have in another column in the same table, called `AssetID`, and could be of any length.  Similarly, the text from "is out of range" onwards can be of any length, but will always start with the string "is out of range".

It is the text in-between the AssetID and "is out of range" that I need to isolate, `(PKG AHU-G37-Pa-A)` but I am struggling to find a way, as this will also be of varying length, so using SubString on its own is not possible.

Any way around this?  I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Are all the rows like this?

Comment: It sounds like you should have multiple columns containing your data and not just one. This way you would not need to do string manipulations for a simple JOIN/lookup.

Comment: No, not all the rows are like this, but we will only be processing the ones that are.

Multiple columns obviously makes the most sense in a normal situation, but here we're basically trying to parse data which has been written to the table from a third-party system.  We have no control over the formatting or which data gets brought across (or to where).

The data we're trying to extract (known to us as the SpecName) is sadly not written from the third-party, so we have to try and extract it from this string instead.  God bless poorly written integrations ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will isolate the text between col2 and the text **is out of range**:

```
SELECT 
  stuff(substring(col1, 0, charindex(' is out of range', col1)), 1,
    len(col2) + 1, '')
FROM yourtable
```

Result:

```
PKG AHU-G37-Pa-A
```

Comment: Dividing a string on its space characters is quite - uhm - brave  :-)

Comment: the OP states, that the beginning (0A10-Deeside) is coming from another column in the same table and that the third part always start with the same phrase (is out of range). I think one should use this information...

Comment: @Shnugo you are right, the answer has been updated. Thanks

Comment: This looks closest to what I need - I'm just confused as to what "stuff" is representing here - or is it just used as an alias for the returned result?

Comment: Ah, ok.  Stuff is an actual function.  Didn't know that!

Comment: Just tested this, and it worked like a charm.  Even managed to identify that my example was wrong, in that the actual AssetID included the " PKG" on the end, giving me the result of just 'AHU-G37-Pa-A'.

Answer (score 1):

Use char index to find the first space and the position of is. feed these back into sub string.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

```
SELECT SubString(theText,0, FirstSpace),....
FROM (
    SELECT CHARINDEX(" ",theText) firstSpace, CHARINDEX(" is",theText) LastSpace, theText
) AS T
```

Comment: The OP states, that the beginning (0A10-Deeside) is coming from another column in the same table and that the third part always start with the same phrase (is out of range). I think one should use this information... Dividing a string by its spaces could be dangerous...

Comment: Indeed, the same method can be used with tighter restrictions which would be better than space. I think the above answer is enough to get the developer pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Sadly the AssetID (the text before the required data) is allowed to contain spaces.  Using CHARINDEX on the columnname AssetID seems to be the better option.

Answer (score 0):

I love the XML type for all the funny things you can do with it. Maybe this approach is something for you, as it is absolutely variable...

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(MAX)='0A10-Deeside PKG AHU-G37-Pa-A is out of range (Current value of 12.000000 is greater than the maximum value of 5.000000)';

DECLARE @testXML XML=CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(@test,'is out of range','</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML);

SELECT x.y.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @testXML.nodes('/root/r') AS x(y);
```

Some enhancements to pick this out of a table, where the beginning is part of another column:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(testText VARCHAR(MAX),AnotherColumn VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('0A10-Deeside PKG AHU-G37-Pa-A is out of range (Current value of 12.000000 is greater than the maximum value of 5.000000)','0A10-Deeside');

SELECT testXML.v.value('/root[1]/r[2]','varchar(max)')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(tbl.testText,'is out of range','</r><r>'),tbl.AnotherColumn,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>' AS XML) 
) AS testXML(v)
```